# endless while loop after mousemove

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am  going crazy here. 
I want to show an element on mouse move, and hide it 10 sec after last move of the mouse.

I wrote this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var time = 0;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    console.log('$');
    document.getElementsByClassName("mybar")[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
    time = 0;
    while (time < 11) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        time++
      }, 1000);
      console.log(time, time == 10);
      if (time == 10) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("mybar")[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class='mybar'>
  <h1> TESTING </h1>
</div>
```

Why does it end up in an endless loop? 
Why doesn't it exit on condition? why does the if never gets the 'true' parameter?
**Notice** : don't run it this way... it will kill your tab.

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you simply trying to show the div for 10 seconds whenever the mouse moves within the window?

Comment: You don't need the `while`.  `setTimeout` does all the timing for you.  You just need to tell it what to call after `n` milliseconds.

Comment: because setTimeout is asynchronous....

Comment: `1000` is one second. `10000` is 10 seconds.

Comment: Because `setTimeout()` is asynchronous, the while loop should end after only one second. Try `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10000)` instead to set a 10 second timeout

Comment: I am trying to hide it 10 sec after the last move of the mouse on the window. When the mouse moves again I want to show it again and hide it again 10 sec after the last move.

Comment: @LambdaNinja increasing the delay will not help. The while loop is going to tie up the thread, which won't allow the setTimeout callback that is waiting in the event queue to be executed, and since it never gets executed the variable never gets incremented, hence the infinite loop.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I meant to use a single 10 second `setTimeout` rather than putting them in a while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to wait for `DOMContentLoaded` to add an event listener to `document`, since if you did, you couldn't add `DOMContentLoaded` in the first place.

The infinite loop is because `setTimeout` doesn't pause the script. It schedules its callback for the time you provide, and irrespective of that time, the callbacks *will not run* until the current running code in the thread completes, which never happens because you don't increment the `time` variable.

So the loop never ends, and so the thread is never made available, so your callbacks never can run, so `time` can never be incremented.

Lastly, starting a `setTimeout` inside an event handler that shares a local variable and executes very rapidly on an event like `mousemove` is prone to give unexpected results. For example, in your code, every  time the handler runs, it'll reset `time` to `0`, which doesn't seem to be what you'd want.

---

A solution would be to ditch the loop, schedule the visibility for 10 seconds, and prevent the main part of the code in the handler from running in the meantime by using a boolean variable.

```
var timer = null;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    var myBar = document.querySelector(".mybar");
    if (!myBar) {
      return; // there's no mybar element
    }


    if (timer == null) {
      myBar.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timer); // clear the currently running timer
    }

    // set to hidden in 10 seconds
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      myBar.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      timer = null; // clear the timer
    }, 10000);
});
```

I also switched to `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName` because it's shorter and cleaner. And I used a variable to make sure the element is found before setting the style.

Comment: Thank you. It is very similar to what I have writen at the beginning.
And it worked, as you code does. The only problem this way is that 10 sec after the first move the bar will disappear... even if the mouse had moved after.

Comment: @matisa: Then if you want it to disappear 10 seconds after the *last* mousemove, what you need to do is *clear* the timeout and start a new one every time there's such an event. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag out of the mousemove scope that tells your listener that you've already ran.

```
if(running) return; 
running = true;
```

In context:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var time = 0;
  var running = false;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {

    console.log('$');

    if(running) return;
    running = true;

    document.getElementsByClassName("mybar")[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
    time = 0;
    while (time < 11) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        time++
      }, 1000);
      console.log(time, time == 10);
      if (time == 10) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("mybar")[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: But in this case it will only run once.
It am building a player. 
I need I want the control bar to disappear 10 sec after the mouse stops moving. On new movement I need it to appear again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with regular JavaScript. If your browser isnt ES6 compliant, you can replace the arrow functions with regular function expressions. The example hides the text after 2 seconds instead of 10, just so you can see it work without having to waste 8 extra seconds.

```js
//hide by default
document.getElementById('myBar').style.display = 'none';

var timer = null;

var hideDivTimer = () => {
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('myBar').style.display = 'none';
  }, 2000);
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  document.getElementById('myBar').style.display = 'inline';
  hideDivTimer();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='myBar'>
    <h1> TESTING </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```